# Does anyone have information about Spiking Neurons or other types of machine learning for images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I'm doing some research on machine learning algorithms that would be useful for processing image data and using them for recognition purposes. I've stumbled across [SpikeNET](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/spikenet/index.html) and thought it had potential. However their example code is very confusing (the comments are in French) and being on a Windows box I cannot compile the project without fiddling around in Cygwin too much.

If anyone has any further information on the Spiking Neuron technology or any other highly researched machine learning techniques that yield good results, I would be highly interested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "machine learning algorithms for processing image data and recognition purposes"? Your question in its current form simply begs for let me google that for you links.

Comment: I searched Google and came up with a list of various different learning techniques (SVM, Neural Networks, Haar Cascades) but I'm unsure of the pros and cons with each or if anyone has had better luck with one or the other. I've seen that a lot of people use Haar Cascades mostly for facial recognition, though, I am trying to use it mostly for logo tracking for feature-less logos. I've had a friend show me the link above and was wondering if anyone had any experience with that as well. I know that this may be a bit much for one question, but I would like to start off strong and in the right area

Comment: I'm sure someone does. What is the question?

Comment: I basically would like to know more about machine learning for image processing and if Spiking Neurons works well or if there are better methods out there.

Comment: On a side note, I'd get used to cygwin or else get a linux box of some sort if you're going to do much in this field, seems like everything is in C. Plus a lot of the command line tools are very helpful for transforming/dealing with data.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for object detection the more "standard" state of art approaches are [haar cascades](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Haar-like_features) and [SIFT features](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform).

As for "working code" have you spent any time at all poking around [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)? this is a very complete computer vision library that can help you along the way. Perhaps start [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ObjectDetection)?